# What are the size limits for HTML 5 client side storage?

Tags: html

What are the size limits for HTML 5 client side storage?

Comment: This page has some great information on HTML5 storage:

http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html

The site itself is a wealth of HTML5 information, too.

Comment: Depends on the user's setting in their browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's around 5 MB per website, but it depends a lot on the browser and the settings of the user.

In Safari, for example, if a website wants to use more than 5 MB, the browser will just ask the user if he wants to let the website use more space.