# Display country, state and city listing

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have got all the countries, theirs states and cities in mysql. I am trying to display country,related states or cities based on user action.

One option is to use javascript/jquery and REST APIs to get all the countries, states based on country id or cities based on country and state id from DB/cache.

Another option is to store these data in browser local storage since I am assuming these data will not have updates that frequently.

My aim is to avoid server calls on user action wherever possible. Will browser allow to store these data since I am not aware of local storage size limit and if yes, is there any way to update local storage whenever there is a change in server side data?

Comment: How big is the data file? Do you care about mobile users?

Comment: table has around 25k records. Yes for mobile users.

Comment: Hmm, what would that be in `MB`? I found this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686624/what-are-the-size-limits-for-html-5-client-side-storage and this http://cloudified.net/blog/2011/04/storage-in-html5-mobile-apps/.

Comment: That would be around 2.5 MB.

Comment: Well, witht the links I gave you, you can decide for yourself. About the updating, do a cycle where you update the storage when you update the server. BTW: You have a REST Api for YOUR server? :o